# SQL Server show distinct values from one column and count number of entries for each distinct

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to show each unique value from column A with a count of how often each value appears ignoring where it has a value of null in column B

I.e

```
Column A     Column B
1              56
1              null
1              78
2              null
3              54
```

I would want a return that looked something like

```
1    2
3    1
```

Comment: Did you happen to Google how to COUNT values in SQL Server?

Comment: select a, count(b) from t group by a having count(b) > 0 order by a

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of GROUP BY on ColumnA, and selecting those records for which ColumnB is not NULL. The following script accomplish your request, i've included some explanations after it

```
CREATE TABLE Test(ColumnA INT, ColumnB INT)

INSERT INTO Test(ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES (1, 56),
                                          (1, null),
                                          (1, 78),
                                          (2, null),
                                          (3, 54)

SELECT ColumnA, COUNT(*)
FROM TEST WHERE ColumnB IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ColumnA

DROP TABLE Test
```

The part of interest is the SELECT instruction. The rest of the script is only for the creation and population of a simple table, like the one you're talking about.

Please note the SELECT is made on ColumnA, and that column is also used in the GROUP BY clause. That means we want to extract single values from ColumnA, in order to select other columns, aggregating them in some way.

That specific aggregation , i.e. the occurence of the values of ColumnB, is made by the aggregate function COUNT(*), which tells to extract the number of those records that matches the grouped column. In our case, COUNT(*) counts the amount of record for each value of ColumnA.
But since you want to exclude those records that have a NULL value for ColumnB, we simply exclude them from the selection through the WHERE clause: as you can see, i'm asking for those records where ColumnB IS NOT NULL.

That way, and using the sample data you've posted, we'll obtain exactly what you expected:

```
1    2
3    1
```